# Angular i18n replace default language in sources

Tags: angular, bash, internationalization

I have an angular 14 i18n project, the default language is French and I have an english translation.

So I have a locale folder with 2 files : `messages.xlf` and `messages.en.xlf`.
Configuration :

```
"i18n": {
  "sourceLocale": "fr",
  "locales": {
    "en": {
      "translation": "src/locale/messages.en.xlf"
    }
  }
```

The code looks like :

.html :

```
<p i18n>Bonjour</p>
```

And .ts :

```
$localize`Bonjour`
```

What I want to do is fully remove the french language and serve only english, I would like to remove the i18n configuration and write everything in english in .html or .ts.

Is there any way to fully replace source files with english translations ?

I checked the angular CLI but didn't find a way to do that, and thought about scripting to replace everything, but it looks tedious...

Answer (score 0):

I ended up scripting it, using `xmllint`, `find` and `sed`, something like this :

```
#!/bin/bash

# Count source nodes
nodeCount=$(xmllint --xpath "count(//trans-unit)" ./src/locale/messages.en.xlf)

#Iterate the nodeset by index
for i in $(seq 1 $nodeCount); do
  source=$(xmllint --xpath "string((//trans-unit)[$i]/source)" ./src/locale/messages.en.xlf)
  target=$(xmllint --xpath "string((//trans-unit)[$i]/target)" ./src/locale/messages.en.xlf)
  filePath=$(xmllint --xpath "string((//trans-unit)[$i]/context-group/context[@context-type='sourcefile'])" ./src/locale/messages.en.xlf)

  gsed -i "s/${source}/${target}/" $filePath >/dev/null 2>&1
  
  advance=$(($i * 100 / $nodeCount))
  echo -ne ">>>                       [${advance}%]\r"
done
```

This script is looking for  tags in the translation file, and find it's matching target and file path.

Warning : It does not works well with plurals but other than that it's pretty good !